# Are these two "notations" the same?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, notation

Say we have a tensor $T^{\sigma\tau}$ and I want to now how it transforms, the transformation coefficients in terms of Lorentz transformation matrices would be: $$T^{\mu'\nu '} = L^{\mu '}{}_{\sigma}L^{\nu '}{}_{\tau}T^{\sigma\tau}.$$ Is this the same as saying $$T^{\mu'\nu '} = \frac{\partial x^{\mu '}}{\partial x^{\sigma}}\frac{\partial x^{\nu '}}{\partial x^{\tau}}T^{\sigma\tau}~?$$ If yes, how/why?

Comment: What are the objects $L^\mu{}_\sigma$? Arbitrary matrices, Lorentz transformations, or something else? (btw, be careful with index positioning!)

Comment: To type the index to the side, type $L^\mu$, then type {} and then put the lower index. In this way, the lower index gets a bit on the front, because it is an index on the invisible {} rather than on $L$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second expression, in terms of partial derivatives, is the definition of the tensor transformation law. Your first equation, in terms of Lorentz transformations, is the special case obtained in special relativity in Cartesian spacetime coordinates, so the partial derivatives are Lorentz transformation matrices.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Say we have a tensor $T^{\sigma\tau}$ and I want to now how it transforms, the transformation coefficients in terms of matrices would be: $T^{\mu\nu '} = L_{\sigma}^{\mu '}L_{\tau}^{\nu '}T^{\sigma\tau}$.

> Is this the same as saying $T^{\mu\nu '} = \frac{\partial x^{\mu '}}{\partial x^{\sigma}}\frac{\partial x^{\nu '}}{\partial x^{\tau}}T^{\sigma\tau}$. If yes, how/why?

It depends on what you mean by $L_{a}^b$.

If you mean
$$
L_{a}^b = \frac{\partial {x'}^b}{\partial x^a}
$$
then yes.

Otherwise no.

Comment: $L^{\mu '}{}_{\sigma}$ is the Lorentz transformation matrix

Comment: I don't know if the Lorentz transformation matrix can be represented in that way, that's why I asked the question

Comment: You did not state that the $L$ were Lorentz transformation matrices when you wrote the question. That would have been helpful to know.